# What's going wrong whith RewriteRule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What is the problem with my .htaccess

This Works:

```
RewriteRule ^ressource\.n\.1/  /lesson  [L,R=permanent]
```

But this, don't work. I don't know why.

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?id=51$ /file/?id=51  [L,R=permanent]
```

I just want when a visitor hit https://www.example.com/index.php?id=51 is going to https://www.example.com/file/?id=51

Thank you!

Comment: I repare my mistakes with this:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.example.com/file/?id=%1 [L,R=301]

Comment: Consider writing that as an "answer", you can then accept it.